# react native how to add alphabet order on side in section list

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native

How to add alphabet order on side in section list?
I checked out some packages such as react-native-atoz and react-native-selectedsectionlist.
What is the best one? or how do I implement one from the scratch?
Here is an example from the iOS contacts app:

[image: Contacts app]

Comment: From my experience using these packages, they don't perform well at all. I implemented my own from scratch but it's also not ideal. I think it is a more deeply seated issue with the react-native architecture.

Comment: Have you implemented it. Can you let us know how you did it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of names what i would do is to split it up by name and made the list you have above. See my [example](https://jsbin.com/tibejecuxo)

So now you can run .map on the array made and display the letter and the names accordingly!

```
const names = [
  "Ned Stark",
  "Robert Baratheon",
  "Jaime Lannister",
  "Catelyn Stark",
  "Cersei Lannister",
  "Daenerys Targaryen",
  "Jorah Mormont",
  "Jon Snow"
]

function getFirstLetterFrom(value) {
  return value.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase();
}

const newNames = names
  .reduce(function (list, name, index) {
      let listItem = list.find((item) => item.letter && item.letter === getFirstLetterFrom(name));
      if (!listItem) {
        list.push({"letter": getFirstLetterFrom(name), "names": [name]})
      } else {
        listItem.names.push(name)
      }

      return list;
  }, []);

console.log(newNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a ready-made solution that works fine [react-native-section-alphabet-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-section-alphabet-list)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33204338)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-section-alphabet-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-section-alphabet-list) package takes an array of data rather than an object with letters as keys.

It gives an alphabetical list when you give an array like

```
const data = [
  { value: 'Lillie-Mai Allen', key: 'lCUTs2' },
  { value: 'Emmanuel Goldstein', key: 'TXdL0c' },
  { value: 'Winston Smith', key: 'zqsiEw' },
  { value: 'William Blazkowicz', key: 'psg2PM' },
  { value: 'Gordon Comstock', key: '1K6I18' },
  { value: 'Philip Ravelston', key: 'NVHSkA' },
  { value: 'Rosemary Waterlow', key: 'SaHqyG' },
  { value: 'Julia Comstock', key: 'iaT1Ex' },
  { value: 'Mihai Maldonado', key: 'OvMd5e' },
  { value: 'Murtaza Molina', key: '25zqAO' },
  { value: 'Peter Petigrew', key: '8cWuu3' },
]
```

And here is the example of that

```
  <AlphabetList
      data={data}
      indexLetterStyle={{ 
        color: 'blue', 
        fontSize: 15,
      }}
      renderCustomItem={(item) => (
        <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.listItemLabel}>{item.value}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      renderCustomSectionHeader={(section) => (
        <View style={styles.sectionHeaderContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderLabel}>{section.title}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

For more Info please visit [react-native-section-alphabet-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-section-alphabet-list) package.

My View
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use [Address Book library for React Native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sectionlist-contacts) to achieve this.

Suggested css styles will look like this:

```
sideView: {
    width: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    right: 0,
}
```